# How to configure softphone in lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, cti

I have installed a package and added user in call center. It is working fine in classic but not able to see that softphone in lightning experience. Is there any settings i have to edit. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make calls in Lightning Experience, complete the following.

- Create a Lightning app and add the Open CTI Softphone to your utility bar.
- In the call center definition file, the reqSalesforceCompatibilityMode item must be set to Lightning or Classic_and_Lightning.

Apart from these configuration change there are many methods which are different in Lightning. So you need to handle them as well.

[Why Your UI Matters—Open CTI for Salesforce Classic vs. Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_intro_lightning_vs_classic.htm)

If this is your first time trying this then I suggest you to go through with this.

[Lightning Open CTI](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Open_CTI)

Comment: thank you @Tushar Sharma first step solved my problem...